# How to show kernel boot messages by modifying grub config files

Tags: grub2, opensuse

`/etc/default/grub` on OpenSUSE Leap 42.2 is like below. How can I change this file in order to be able to see boot-time kernel messages:

```
# If you change this file, run 'grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub2/grub.cfg.

# Uncomment to set your own custom distributor. If you leave it unset or empty, the default
# policy is to determine the value from /etc/os-release
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=8
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="resume=/dev/sda4 splash=silent quiet showopts"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to automatically save last booted menu entry in GRUB2 environment

# variable `saved_entry'
# GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT="true"
#Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs

# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
# GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"
#Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)

GRUB_TERMINAL="gfxterm"
# The resolution used on graphical terminal
#note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE

# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
GRUB_GFXMODE="auto"
# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
# GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true
#Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries

# GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_RECOVERY="true"
#Uncomment to get a beep at grub start

# GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
GRUB_BACKGROUND=/boot/grub2/themes/openSUSE/background.png
GRUB_THEME=/boot/grub2/themes/openSUSE/theme.txt
SUSE_BTRFS_SNAPSHOT_BOOTING="true"
GRUB_USE_LINUXEFI="true"
GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER="false"
GRUB_ENABLE_CRYPTODISK="n"
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Removing `quiet` and `splash` generally does the job. Change this:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="resume=/dev/sda4 splash=silent quiet showopts"
```

to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="resume=/dev/sda4 showopts"
```

I actually use `initcall_debug` and `no_console_suspend` too to get as much detail as possible for debugging, but if everything is working smoothly, those extra parameters won't make any difference.

Don't forget to run `grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg` after changing the file.

Comment: Is there no shortcut for that `grub2-mkconfig` on SUSE?